# how to set attributes for body inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set a some attributes for body in iframe .

```
<div id="itemdiv" >
  <iframe id="ifr" name='iframe1' src="//codepen.io/anhdayem818/pen/EjOQZE.html" ></iframe>
</div>
```

code js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#itemdiv').attr('abc','123');
  $(window.iframe1.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).attr('abc','123'); 
});
```

code here:  http://codepen.io/anhdayem818/pen/eNQVWe

when i run, div tag add a attributes `<div id="itemdiv" abc="123">` 
but  body tag don't set attributes,

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the document inside an iframe, it has to do with the `same-origin policy` (you can read it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)).
You could have a second script in the iframe page that does the work you need. 
If you need to have it done on command and not just automatically (let's say, after the user presses a button in your main page), you should have a script in your main page that comunicate with the script inside the iframe page.
You can use the `.postMessage()` method for that; you can read more about it [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage).